The shell cannot be started (issue with VS Code)
I'm learning how to code and I'm using VS Code, and when trying to open the terminal or to open a file with internal terminal it give me an error message and then the terminal closes.
What would be the reason for this? and how can I solve it?
Installed latest version of PowerShell and reinstalled VS code

How about fixing the problem which is described by the error message?

@user1934428: Given that the terminal closes right away, there may not be enough time to read the error message.

@mklement0 : True, and maybe the time is so short, that we can't even recognize that it is an error message, but if this were the case, I think the OP would have described it. For instance it could be that the terminal is configured in a way that it starts a shell script, which prints something to stdout and terminates. However nowadays it's trivial to take a short video clip of the situation, and do a playback in slow motion and pause it at the time the mysterious message is visible, so this shouldn't be a real problem either.

@mkelement0 : Good idea. I've never worked with Powershell, and the colouring of error message is for sure good to know. In this case, wouldn't it be sufficient to just open a cmd console window, instead of creating a new VSC profile? If you are right and the problem depends solely on Powershell (I'm not convinced), this would then be the fastest way to nail down the error.

@user1934428 (sorry, reposting this due to a typo): The problem is PowerShell-related, and PowerShell's error messages print in red, which would make it easy to infer that an error is being shown, even if there's not enough time to read its text. While your suggested video solution may work, it strikes me as far from trivial. A much simpler solution is to switch to cmd.exe as the default profile and invoke PowerShell from there to see the error, as suggested in the answer.

@user1934428: You don't need to create a new VSC profile, you can simply (temporarily) switch to the built-in cmd.exe (Command Prompt) profile for troubleshooting (as also described in the answer). There you can manually invoke whatever command line is in the original default shell definition, if any, or simply the CLI of the original default shall.

You don't state the error message (perhaps it appears too briefly for you to read it before the terminal closes), but the implication is that your problem is with your default shell profile, which appears to be PowerShell (as it would be by default on Windows).[1]
To troubleshoot:

Make a note of what your current default profile name is:

Open your settings.json file for editing as follows: From the command palette, select Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON) (searching for user json should be enough to locate it).

Search for a "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows" property (on Linux, replace windows with linux, on macOS with osx).

If present, its value is the name of the default profile.

If not present, the built-in profile named PowerShell is the default on Windows, which either refers to PowerShell (Core) 7 - if installed in a standard location - or Windows PowerShell (the legacy edition of PowerShell that ships with Windows) otherwise.





Try making a different profile the default:

From the command palette (select menu command View > Command Palette... or press Ctrl+Shift+P to open it), select Terminal: Select Default Profile (just typing default profile should be enough to locate it).

From the list of available shell profiles, select Command Prompt (C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe).

Then try to open the integrated terminal again (Ctrl+`): If this successfully creates a cmd.exe session that stays open, then the problem must be with the configuration of your original, PowerShell-based shell profile.

Note that if you have PowerShell (Core) 7 installed (in a standard location), Visual Studio Code will default to it, and use Windows PowerShell (the built-in legacy edition of PowerShell) otherwise.




Examine your shell profiles, via settings.json:

Open your settings.json file again and search for the "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows" property, if present. If so, examine and fix the profile definition in the sub-property named for the original default profile, if present.

The Terminal Profiles documentation discusses the expected format and has background information.

If you managed to switch to cmd.exe (Command Prompt) as the default profile, open the integrated terminal and try invoking the command line specified in the profile definition there, which should give you a chance to examine the error message.



If no profile is present for the original default profile (which implies that a built-in profile is used).

Then the problem is likely with your PowerShell 7 installation; if you managed to switch to cmd.exe (Command Prompt) as the default profile, open the integrated terminal and try invoking pwsh.exe from there, which should give you a chance to examine the error message.






[1] The fact that the integrated terminal closes every time, as you state, implies that the problem is not the so-called PIC (PowerShell-Integrated Console), which is a special-purpose PowerShell shell for authoring and debugging PowerShell code that comes with the PowerShell extension. If the PIC were the problem, then opening the integrated terminal again after a crash would run the default shell instead. For PIC-related problems, see the official troubleshooting instructions.

The issue was in powershell itself, it seemed that the version I downloaded was either not the leatest or it was 32 instead of 64, so I downloaded the last "correct" version of powershell, and it worked roght away.
